# How to generate a random number in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to add an RNG function to my bot. The problem is that `random` module (as far as I know) doesn't allow to change percentage. For example, I want to have 40% to get int `1` and 60% to get int `2`. This will of course change.

I thought about creating a list with 100 elements in it. For example, 40 elements will be int `1` and 60 int `2`, but I think that's not good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can possibly use `random.choices`, eg:

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    nums = random.choices([1, 2], weights=[0.4, 0.6], k=10)
    print(i, nums)
```

Gives you:

```
0 [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
1 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
2 [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
3 [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2]
4 [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
5 [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
6 [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
7 [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
8 [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
9 [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Which should be close enough although doesn't offer a guarantee of exact 40/60 splitting as random is sometimes, well, random...